# Change Symbology with different Column Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

I am trying to change Cadastre colours when the values of the box EXTRA is set to 0,1 or 2.
So basically, I need the default values set to 0 (already completed).
Properties that have to be invested have a value set to 1 (completed).
Properties with further information needed value set to 2 (completed onsite).

To make it user friendly I would like to set up the symbology colour to change the polygons to different colours depending on the EXTRA value.

0 = clear
1 = green
2 = red

I have tried both Quantities and Multiple Attributes but neither get the result I am after.

Using the 'Graduated Colors', changing Fields Value to EXTRA only gives one symbol when I would want three? If I have three then I will be able to change the range and respective colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a polygon feature class where you have multiple polygons. Each polygon has a value stored in the field named Extra. You want to show polygons with unique colors.

You should use the [Unique values symbology](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/Drawing_a_layer_using_categories/00s50000003m000000/) in ArcMap. You can then choose what color your polygons with a certain value will show.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for that!